# What is the problem in the Connection-String EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, connection-string

I build a web api project in c#, using the three layers technology [DAL, BL, GUI-(in angular, but it's not the matter)]. 
I connected c# to SQL server by EntityFramework. 
this is the connection-string:

```
   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ReturningLostItemsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ReturningLostItemsModel.csdl|res://*/ReturningLostItemsModel.ssdl|res://*/ReturningLostItemsModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-V5DR227;initial catalog=ReturningLostItems;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I have a controller in c#, that returns answer to the client.
When I run the application and open the browser (or Postman) in the url ("http://localhost:53985/Items/GetItems"), It gives me an error :
 `{"Message": "No connection string named 'ReturningLostItemsEntities' could be found in the application config file."}`

this is the controller:

```
 [RoutePrefix("Items")]
    public class ItemsController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetItems")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetItems()
        {
            try
            {
            var items = BusinessLayer.ItemBL.GetItems();
            if (items != null)
                    return Ok(items);
                return NotFound();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the class in the BusinessLayer:

```
 public class ItemBL
    {
        //add item
        public static DataTransferObject.Item AddItem(DataTransferObject.Item item)
        {
            return Converters.ItemConverter.ConvertItemToDTO(DataAccessLayer.ItemDAL.AddItem(Converters.ItemConverter.ConvertItemToDAL(item)));
        }

        //get items
        public static List<DataTransferObject.Item> GetItems()
        {
            return Converters.ItemConverter.ConvertListItemToDTO(DataAccessLayer.ItemDAL.GetItems());
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's no issue here. What you need to show us is the BusinessLayer. How have you defined `ReturningLostItemsEntities`. my guess would be as a global variable and defined in the constructor but we can't tell this unless you show us

Comment: Please share your business layer, the problem should be over there.

Comment: The `connectionString` should be specified in the web.config of the *startup* project, is it where it's defined?

Comment: I added the Class of the BusinessLayer